# Lua. Как получить цифры из строки?

Tags: lua

Всем привет.
У меня есть такой текст: "[/arep] Nick_Name[26]:"
Как мне получить из этой строки его ID? То есть 26?
Пробовал так:

```
local id = string.match(text, "[/arep]%s%a[%d+]:")
```

Но не получалось.

Comment: Надо экранировать [

Comment: @becouse поможете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такое регулярное выражение позволит получить все группы цифр в квадратных скобках

```
\[\d+\]
```

Lua не имеет регулярных выражений, в основном потому, что полная библиотека регулярных выражений была бы больше, чем сама Lua.

Вместо этого в Lua есть соответствующие шаблоны, которые гораздо менее мощные (но все же достаточные для многих случаев использования):

В синтаксисе lua другой формат шаблонов. [Подробнее](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)

```
s = "[/arep] Nick_Name[26]:"

res= string.match(s, "%[(%d+)%]")

print(res)
```

Comment: VsCode подсвечивает красным, как правильно написать в ковычках?

Comment: Сделал так: "\\[\\d+\\]", но в переменную помещается не цифры, а nil (пустота)

Comment: Заработало!!!! спасибо вам огромнешйшее!!! столько мучений!!

Answer (score 0):

```
local id = string.gsub(str,'^(%[/arep%])(.*)%[(%d+)%]:$','%3');
```

Comment: Что-то не работает..
пишет:
bad argument #1 to 'gsub' (string expected, got nil)
stack traceback

Comment: str поменяйте на text

Comment: А, нет, это я протупил, ввёл вместо своей строки вашу str, но всё равно не работает. Выводится полная строка, а не только ID

Comment: поменял, всё равно выводится полный текст, и ковычки из ординарных поменял на двойные, выводится вместо ID полный текст, почему то
код:
local id = string.gsub(text,"^(%[/arep%])(.*)%[(%d+)%]:$","%3");
            
            sampSendChat("gg "..id)

Comment: Приведите ваш код, пожалуйста. Я попробовал в онлайн редакторе и работает: https://rextester.com/BRC15131

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но выше уже есть рабочее решение.